# Parsec match single unicode character

Tags: haskell, unicode, parsec

I'm trying to create a parser (with parsec), that parses tokens, delimited by newlines, commas, semicolons and unicode dashes (ndash and mdash):

```
authorParser = do
    name <- many1 (noneOf [',', ':', '\r', '\n', '\8212', '\8213'])
    many (char ',' <|> char ':' <|> char '-' <|> char '\8212' <|> char '\8213')
```

But the ndash-mdash (\8212, \8213) part never 'succeeds' and i'm getting invalid parse results.

How do i specify unicode dashes with char parser?

P.S. I've tried (chr 8212), (chr 8213) too. It doesn't helps.

*ADDITION*: It is better to use Data.Text. The switch from ByteStrings madness to Data.Text saved me a lot of time and 'source space' :)

Comment: I think the encoding problems should be a new question, not enough space to treat that in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec> let authorName = do { name <- many1 (noneOf ",:\r\n\8212\8213"); many (oneOf ",:-\8212\8213"); }
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec> parse authorName "" "my Name,\8212::-:\8213,"
Right ",\8212::-:\8213,"
```

How did you try?

The above was using plain `String`, which works without problems because a `Char` is a full uncode code point. It's not as nice with other types of input stream. `Text` will probably also work well for this example, I think that the dashes are encoded as a single code unit there. For `ByteString`, however, things are more complicated. If you're using plain `Data.ByteString.Char8` (strict or lazy, doesn't matter), the `Char`s get truncated on packing, only the least significant 8 bits are retained, so '\8212' becomes 20 and '\8213' becomes 21. If the input stream is constructed the same way, that still kind of works, only all `Char`s congruent to 20 or 21 modulo 256 will be mapped to the same as one of the dashes.

However, it is likely that the input stream is UTF-8 encoded, then the dashes are encoded as three bytes each, "\226\128\148" resp. "\226\128\149", which doesn't match what you get by truncating. Trying to parse utf-8 encoded text with `ByteString` and `parsec` is a bit more involved, the units of which the parse result is composed are not single bytes, but sequences of bytes, 1-4 in length each.

To use `noneOf`, you need an

```
instance Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream ByteString m Char
```

which does the right thing. The instance provided in `Text.Parsec.ByteString[.Lazy]` doesn't, it uses the `Data.ByteString[.Lazy].Char8` interface, so an en-dash would become a single '\20' not matching '\8212' or produce three `Chars`, '\226', '\128' and '\148' in three successive calls to `uncons`, none of which matches '\8212' either, depending on how the input was encoded.

Comment: Hmm. If i switch from (noneOf [...]) to (noneOf "...") it fails at even earlier stage. Maybe this is somehow connected with ByteString.Lazy, which i am using?

Comment: Ah. `ByteString`, that's a clue. Adding to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i've managed to make noneOf/oneOf work 'correctly', at least with usual characters. But -- do i need to write my own uncons for var-length characters?

Comment: No, you can use the `uncons` function from `Data.ByteString[.Lazy].UTF8` from the `utf8-string` package. But, it's not nice to have two different `Stream` instances for `ByteString` and `Char` (and they can't be used together), so you should consider to make a `newtype` wrapper around `ByteString` for using utf-8 encoded `ByteStrings`. However, if it's just a quick hack that'll never leave your `$HOME`, you can be dirty and just write a second instance ignoring the one from `Text.Parsec.ByteString[.Lazy]`.

Comment: You should do some benchmarks to see if using bytestring-utf8 saves you anything over String when used with Parsec.

Comment: I'm using ByteString because of ZipArchive exposes compressed zip-entries in ByteString :). I think, if i won't be able to get thru this -- i will unpack entries.

Comment: That's a good point, @Antoine. Another option that should be relatively painless and performant is using `Text`.

Comment: @zw0rk but make sure whether to unpack with `D.BS.Char8` or `D.BS.UTF8`.

Comment: I'm already using Char8 to pack/unpack, but with UTF8.uncons i'm getting weird output (incorrect decoding/encoding, i guess).

I'm a Haskell newbie, i apologize if i'm too stupid.

Comment: @zw0rk Well, is the data utf-8 encoded? That was just a guess because it's the most common.

Comment: Yes, it is. Before the uncons replacement the output was normal, and i'm using iconv to convert from cp1251 to utf8 before using parsec. [iconv -- because encodings hackage failed to install]